# I lost my DOT heavy truck logbook what do I do?

Tags: united-states, driving, regulations

I have to keep a Class A driver log book even though I work in my local area driving logs. The log book is used to keep track of proper rest. I lost mine. What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is almost certainly a policy that covers this. You should probably follow it. There might be disciplinary consequences but I doubt a first offense would be too serious. The longer you go before reporting it the worse it might look.